# Run-time Error 9 w/Variable Workbook Name

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

So the user is able to import data from another excel file and I want to close the other excel file once the values have been copied into the current workbook. I can't, however, get my code to go back and select the other excel file in order to close it again.

I've already checked and it's only running one instance of Excel.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Button_ImportSubmittedData_Click()
        Dim MyFile As String
        Dim tempDataSetName As String

        tempDataSetName = "Submitted Apps"

        MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files,*.xlsx")
            Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=MyFile
            ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
            ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Windows("HET.xlsm").Activate
            Sheets("Submitted").Select
            ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Selection.Columns.AutoFit
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
            **Windows(MyFile).Activate**
            'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            'ActiveWindow.Close
            'Windows("HET.xlsm").Activate
            'ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to go activate it or anything to close it - just use `Workbooks(MyFile).Close False`

Comment: Unfortunately the `Workbooks(MyFile).Close False` isn't working either; I'm still getting the same runtime error @dwirony

Comment: Did you want `Workbooks.OpenText` or `Workbooks.Open` - sounds like the latter.

Comment: Add a `Dim wb as Workbook`, then `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFile)`. Now you have an object variable you can reference: `wb.Close False`

Comment: Try `Dim myWorkbook as Workbook` and `Set myWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook`, just after you open it. Then later when you're ready to close, use `myWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False`.

Comment: Thank you; that worked! @PeterT and BigBen!